# Long Operation Status

Tags: .net, user-interface, oop

When performing a long operation in your application, how do you promote information from your business tier to your UI?

Events?
Passing in a status object which is hooked to the UI?

Before I start I just wondered what cunning ways you guys and girls have come up with.

Comment: And what about nested operations, eg. a main function is called which calls a number of sub functions, each provide progress and can be called in their own right.

Comment: I've written some code on this, you can find it here http://www.antix.co.uk/A-Developers-Blog/Long-Operation-Status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I usually do this:

1. Pushing data with events. Quite simply, the long method knows how much it's done and whenever it finishes a piece it raises an event and pushes data to the UI.
2. Polling. Suppose the method is for reading a file. It will always update a property somewhere with its progress, and the UI will poll that property once every 100-200ms to update the progress. The reason for 100-200ms is that lower than that the user won't notice and it will only slow down the operation; higher and the progress would be 'clunky'.

Comment: I find polling very effective too. Events work fine, mostly, but they *do* slow down running code if you must synchronize threads, so use events sparingly, only in outer/bigger loops.

Comment: Polling is good only in cases when events would fire too fast, I think. Note that events don't have to slow down code because they can be raised in their own thread, and if going to the UI should use BeginInvoke and not Invoke()

Answer (score 0):

You should make a difference between: this can be done in a GUI-app and this needs to be done in batch.

Something that runs for 5 minutes: in your gui-app or in batch?

Comment: This would be an application with a GUI and a buisness layer doing the work

Comment: ok, very good. But what I'm trying to say is: if you think the process is running for too long, it's perhaps better to do all the work in batch.

Comment: thanks but no, this is a question about providing feeback to a user specifically not using a batch

Answer (score 0):

If we consider a typical Web app - one that is not using a push technology such as COMET, updated information will be fetched by the browser intermittely, perhaps when the user requests, perhaps when an AJAX background call is made.

In that scenario I have my service offering a Status operation.

```
 int requestSomeWork( ... data ... ) ; // returns an id

 Status getStatus( int id );  // tell me about a previously submitted request
```

This style is useful not only for displaying progress information but also in recovery from failure scenarios. I may provide additional methods so that we can determine what happened if the Browser or Server crashes just as we were creating a request

```
 int[] findRequest( ... search Criteria ... );  // I think I submitted a request like ... what's its id?
```

If we have a "live" UI, either thick client or COMET then we can add event processing

```
 void registerForUpdates( id, callMe );
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems exactly what events are designed for. Letting other objects know about changes to that object.

Having an ProgressUpdated event that reports a progress percentage or something along lines is how I would do it.

Comment: ok, so how about passing an object which raises events through methods, like IncrementStatus(). That way you can have one object which you can use again for different operations on different objects and have the UI hook up to it?